# looking for a strategy to avoid cyclic dependency in PostgreSQL schemas

Tags: postgresql-9.1

In my db, I have `schema a` with entities that depend upon `schema b`, and `schema b` has entities that depend on `schema a`. This came about over a year of incremental development. Now, migrating the db to another server is failing. When I `pgdump` a schema from one server and try to `pg_restore` it on the other server, it croaks. What can I do to get around, both for now, and as a good strategy for the future?

Comment: Just to confirm, are you using the pg_dump executable from 9.1?